# Why is Docker entrypoint script not executed in detached mode?

Tags: docker

Assume this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And entrypoint.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
exec "$@"
```

Now if I build the image and create the container in foreground, the entrypoint script is executed:

```
$ docker build . -t mytest
[...]
$ docker run --rm -it mytest /bin/bash
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
root@3e3d7290b09c:/#
```

But if I create the container in detached mode, it is not executed:

```
$ docker run --rm -d -it mytest /bin/bash
f8e72a222c5194f61843569ae76798bb09736fa4205b93e484f11de32df4db64
```

Why is that? Or, more importantly, how can I create a detached container, where the entrypoint script is executed?

Comment: Take a look at the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground). When you are not in detached mode, you can *attach* your STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR per the `-a` flag. Try passing that `-a` when you are in `-d` mode, you will be met with an error. Being in *detached* mode, your process is running in the background and is not outputting to your stdout.

Comment: If you run `docker logs f8e72a22` you should see the output of your container, starting with your `echo` statement.

Comment: Good call @DavidMaze that's true.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Especially for the `logs` command - that's a great one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d)

> -d=false: Detached mode: Run container in the background, print new container id

Detach modes are generally made for services not standalone scripts if you want to see the output. You can use detached mode on standalone scripts if you don't want to see the output. Services that should be ran in detached mode would include databases, web servers, est. Not one time ran scripts that go and quit.

Your container runs in the background then quits because the script has ended. Since `-d` option only prints out the container id that is all you will see

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it better now. I actually do want to run a standalone-script and see the output of it. However, before I can execute it, I already need an existing container, because I have to copy some files into it (and no, I can't do that with the Dockerfile). So my sequence is `docker run -d ...`, then `docker cp ...` and then `docker exec -it ... my-standalone-script`. Perhaps `run -d` is not the right way to create the container?

Comment: +1 for the answer here.. if you want to run more commands combined i suggest you sequence them in the dockerfile instead of passing them to docker cli